# Where can I find Chinese character bopomofo/pinyin data?

Tags: internationalization, dataset, chinese-locale, opendata

I'm looking for a datasets with all the Chinese character Mandarin pronunciations in bopomofo and/or pinyin. Also, I need open source datasets that I can copy into my own code bases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you might be looking for the Unihan Database. The Unihan Database is maintained by the Unicode Consortium.

> The Unihan database is the repository for the Unicode Consortium’s collective knowledge
> regarding the CJK Unified Ideographs contained in the Unicode Standard. It contains
> mapping data to allow conversion to and from other coded character sets and additional
> information to help implement support for the various languages which use the Han
> ideographic script.

For an example, here is [the data for 爱](https://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=7231).

Here is [the description of the organization and content](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr38/index.html) of the Unihan Database. Be sure to read that to understand what the data is referring to.

If this is the information you want, you can [download the ZIP archive](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/Unihan.zip) that contains all this data.

The Unihan Database doesn't have Bopomofo (Zhuyin) pronunciations, but it has Pinyin readings. Converting from Pinyin to Zhuyin is simple; there are a lot of online tools that can do it for you.

As for licensing issues, the Unihan Database data files have [a liberal copyright notice](http://www.unicode.org/copyright.html#Exhibit1). So, you shouldn't run into any problems using that data in your own software.

Comment: Thanks! I had found [another database](http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=cedict), but unihan seems to be a better fit for the problem. I also wrote a JS pinyin to zhuyin converter: https://github.com/nathanathan/pinyinToZhuyin

Answer (score 0):

this is a bit of a late entry but I was searching for the same thing last year and ended up compiling my own character/bopomofo database based on a bunch of different data sets. I have put enough work into this thing to thoroughly call it my own though so you should check it out! its part of a rubygem I made to sort by bopomofo (I had a system that would not let me change the database colaltion settings) https://github.com/nallan/a-b-chi